# Avante 2010 M16 GDI 1.6L Fuel Type

Tags: fuel-system, hyundai, elantra, octane

I own an imported Avante 2012 M16 GDI 1.6L from Korea (basicly an Elantra with extra options).

The 400 page plus manual and all references on the internet are in Korean, so I have no clue what type of fuel I'm supposed to use with it.

We have Octane 90 and 95, I've been pumping Octane 95 into it fearing that 90 is not supported, but I don't want to keep wasting money if that was not the case.

Can you help me figure out the best fuel type to use?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the engine turbocharged? I don't know what your *exact* answer is, but would bet if it's turbo'd, use the higher grade of fuel. If it's naturally aspirated, you could use the lower.

Comment: It's not supercharged, that's for sure. and yeah I'm leaning into the lower so far.